# How can I seed my database with English like languages using Faker library?

Tags: laravel-5.5, faker

I'm working with Laravel 5.5 and recently I seed( filling up with dummy values) my database using Faker library. But the language used by the Faker library was too strange to me. Is there a way that tells Faker library to seed my database in English?

Comment: What do you mean "too strange"? If you take a look at the faker library, It uses `en_US` as his default locale.

Comment: No..it's a different language

Comment: Can I change the language used by the Faker library

Comment: Can you give me an example of "too strange"?

Answer (score 1):

To change the faker default locale, add this to your `config/app.php`:

```
'faker_locale' => 'en_US',
```

the list of provider listed in `vendor/fzaninotto/faker/src/Faker/Provider` folder.